# Skin Editing/Overlaying bullet holes

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0

You see, especially in FPS games, when a bullet hits a wall or a character, etc. You end up with the bullet hole.

Is this usually done with the actual skin temporarily changing, or just an overlay of another image (or something totally different)?

Could anyone give me pointers on how to go about this? I'm using XNA (C#)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A naive solution would be to use a small quad positioned and rotated to match the surface where the bullet hit with a transparent texture of a bullet hole.

There are some more advanced techniques involved if you want the hole to clip properly if you shoot near an edge of a wall, or if you shoot something rounded.

These are called "decals" if you want to look into more details.  Here's a blog post that goes into some of those techniques. http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/06/how-to-project-decals/